# Azure Website GitDeploy Website Project

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-git-deployment

Unfortunately we need to use a Visual Studio Website Project not a Visual Studio Web Application Project!
That means that our website to publish has no .csproj
We now try to setup git deployment for our azure website. however it tells me there is no project file to deploy. It seems that the azure git deployment always tries to deploy a web application project not a website project.
Do you know how i can tell the git deployment to make a website project deploy?
best
laurin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking to [Customize your deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site) this is done by including a `.deployment` file in the root of your application. It will instruct [kudu](http://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) the deployment engine in Azure Websites which folder to deploy instead of relying on the csproj.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `.deployment` file to the root of your repository.

```
.git
.deployment         <----- this file
DirOne
    DirTwo
        WebsiteRoot           <----- points to this directory
            App_Data
            bin
            etc
            Web.config
```

Add the following lines to the `.deployment` file.

```
[config]
project = DirOne/DirTwo/WebsiteRoot
```

See also: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site

Comment: After hours of research, I came exactly to this approach, but it didn't work for a simple PHP Linux website in Azure, when pushing got error "Could not find the .NET Core project file".